# Unable to locate package maven

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install `maven` with the command `sudo apt-get install maven`, but I keep on getting this error

```
E: unable to locate package maven
```

I have been googling and tried updating, upgrading, and few other things but nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

`maven` is in the Universe repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Comment: @Sanobabu As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: This gives this error: E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common

Comment: I have java 8 installed. Why does `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` lookout for java 6?